# Changing text file encoding does not effect the text

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, notepad++, notepad

I tried to change the encoding of ANSI files (àìà ìùîåø) to UTF8.
I was manage to do that in the pass.

Now when i try to do the same thing, the encoding setting is changing but the weird character does not change and does not seems to get any effect.
I have tried with any good editors like notepad++ notepad2 notepad3 with no success.
I think that the problem is in my machine.

What could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a text file which has "weird characters", you open it in Notepad++, change the encoding and save it? Nope, that won't do a thing. It will just make Notepad++ save the weird character in a different encoding. If you need to fix a broken text file, it depends on how it got broken.

Comment: It originally saved as ANSI that's why the "weird characters".
We are talking about subtitles file.

I did the same with notepad on other machine and that's worked.
This is the same method i used in the pass and its worked.

Comment: The actual version of [Notepad3](https://www.rizonesoft.com/downloads/notepad3/) 5.19 manages very well the encoding feature, perhaps it was a bug...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Office 2003 open Word copy the text and select it then go to tools -> fix broken text and choose your language. this will convert the text back to its original state